# Quick way to do repetitive task? Point feature class (paste one field value from one feature class to another)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am identifying certain points in one feature class within ArcMap and want to quickly make a separate point feature class in the same location and paste a value from the first feature class into the new point feature class.

Is there a quicker way to do this than my current method, which is to copy the feature and paste it (into the new feature class then paste the attribute from one to the other)?

Comment: As I read your question you basically want to create a subset of the points and keep one of the attributes? In which case copy the whole data set, select the points you want to keep, reverse the selection and delete everything else.

Comment: Is the destination fc a one off layer (just created once) or something that needs features appended to it overtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I have misunderstood your issue it sounds like you need only to SELECT the points and EXPORT the selection to a new feature class?  You could select your points manually or use the select by attribute tool then right click on the layer in the TOC and go to Data > export and export the selection.